# Titan start fails: management.properties not found

Tags: cassandra, titan

I downloaded and unziped the titan.zip and used the command `./titan.sh -v start`. Now I get the output:

`./titan.sh -v start
Forking Cassandra...
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: The UseParNewGC flag is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Running nodetool statusthrift.Error: Config file not found: /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-1.9.0/jre/conf/management/management.properties
...... timeout exceeded (60 seconds)
See /home/hausi/Documents/titan-0.5.4-hadoop2/bin/../log/cassandra.log for Cassandra log output.`

The file `management.properties` does not exist on my machine. I could find any information about. Is it necessary to run Titan? How can I create it?

Little of topic bonus question: Since the company behind Titan was bought, will the database developmend be stopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are running JDK9?

> /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-1.9.0/jre/conf/management/management.properties

If I'm not misreading that, I think the answer is to downgrade to JDK7 or JDK8.

> Since the company behind Titan was bought, will the database development be stopped?

The short answer is "no" and that development will continue.  Please read:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/WTNYYpUyrvw/pZh02Q2LlpsJ