# Zookeeper server start/server connection issue

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup Zookeeper with single server ensemble on my Ubuntu machine.
I started server with success message and was expecting it as started.

```
akshay@akshay:~$ /var/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /var/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
akshay@akshay:~$
```

But it seems server was never started though logs says started.
I also tried starting server without start option as suggested in similar questions which was again not a success.

I verified this with below ways.

1. Server Status

   akshay@akshay:~$ /var/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh status
   ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
   Using config: /var/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
   Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
2. Tried kazoo client to connect to server and end up with timeout error.

   from kazoo.client import KazooClient
   zk_client = KazooClient(hosts='127:0:0:1:2181')
   zk_client.start()

> Output:
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KazooTimeoutError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 zk_client.start()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kazoo/client.pyc in start(self,
>   timeout)
>       544             # We time-out, ensure we are disconnected
>       545             self.stop()
>   --> 546             raise self.handler.timeout_exception("Connection time-out")
>       547 
>       548         if self.chroot and not self.exists("/"):
>
> KazooTimeoutError: Connection time-out

Below is my zoo.cfg

```
akshay@akshay:~$ cat /var/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.9/conf/zoo.cfg
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/var/zookeeper/data
clientPort=2181
```

Can someone please help if I am missing anything during the process.
I followed setup steps from [apache zookeeper doc](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here was version compatibility of zookeeper and java 9 based on today's date(2016-11-13). I reverted back to java 8 and things went fine.

But still open question is why server start gave false message as `Starting zookeeper ... STARTED`

I figured this issue by looking at zookeeper.out file which said something like

```
Config file not found: /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-1.9.0/jre/conf/management/management.properties
```

Further steps were taken as answer suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662829/titan-start-fails-management-properties-not-found).

Comment: I just confirmed, changing Java 9 to 8 solves this problem. Thanks!

Comment: How do I tell ZooKeeper which java version to use?